# Find f(x) for an arbitrary x

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I try using substitution where $u = \frac{x-1}{x}$ but I just get confused later when doing the algebra. Here's the question. What's the simplest way to solve it?

Let $f$ be a function that satisfies $f(\frac{x-1}{x})= 1 - \frac{3}{x+1}$ for all $x$ except $x = 0 $ and $x = -1 $. Find $f(x)$ for an arbitrary $x$. What is the domain of $f$?

Isn't the domain all real numbers but 1, because $\frac{x-1}{x}$ would be undefined there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with your substitution we obtain $x=\frac{1}{1-u}$ and our $f(u)$ is
$$f(u)=1-\frac{3}{\frac{1}{1-u}+1}=1-\frac{3(1-u)}{2-u}$$

Comment: I guess my problem is getting from the substitution to the final result. I get up to $1-\frac{3x}{2x-1}$ and confused. Also, is the way I solved for domain right?

Comment: @KillerSmalls: No, your domain "all real numbers but 1" is not correct. As you see in Dr. Graubner's answer, the final denominator is $2-u$, so the actual domain is "all real numbers but 2."